# Rendering Error 3ds max

Tags: max, 3ds

Hello i made a 3d environment:

[image]

Red parts.
I try to change materials but nothing.
I delete reflection and error fixed, but why rendering makes red parts?
I haven't  red objects in the scene.

Info.: 3ds max 2015 - vRay 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have unsupported materials on the scene or when there are invalid colors generated.
Make sure you're using vray materials and that reflected objects do as well.